# How to show which repositories changed when repo sync

Tags: repo

Is there a way, where I can list which repositories have been updated by last `repo sync`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit heavy but it's the only way I can think of:

```
repo manifest -r > before-sync
repo sync
repo manifest -r > after-sync
repo diffmanifests before-sync after-sync
```

To get more info on the output of `repo diffmanifests` see the doc:

```
repo help diffmanifests
```